# Vertical panning with dynamic data loading in Google Charts

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I would like to implement a horizontally scrollable chart for some time series data, which would fetch the data dynamically from the back-end for the actually shown period. I am experimenting with the explorer option of Google Charts, however I understand that it needs the full time series data already fetched. Is it possible to load only upon panning?

Comment: In order to do this, you would need to be able to know when the user panned the chart, but the charts do not fire events for explorer actions, so there is no way to know currently.

Comment: I see - could you suggest an alternative to Google Charts which has this feature?